# Prove that $x-x^2$ is a Contraction

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

In trying to prove that the function $f(x)=x-x^2$, where $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is a contraction with the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$, I need to show that the following holds:
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y| \quad\equiv\quad|x-x^2-y+y^2|\leq|x-y|.
$$
So far, I have only been able to show that:
$$
|x-x^2-y+y^2|\leq|x|+|y|,
$$
because the domain of $f$ is restricted to $[0,1]$, for each $x\in[0,1]$, we have $x^2\leq x$ and furthermore $x-x^2\leq x$. But, since $|x-y|\leq|x|+|y|$, it did not help me. I have tried to factor $|x-y|$:
$$
|x-x^2-y+y^2|\leq\,|x-y|+|y^2-x^2|=|x-y|\left( 1+|x+y|\right).
$$
However I cannot see that helping me either. Any ideas of how to conduct the proof are most appreciated.

Comment: Just a random thought: Consider writing $y$ as $x+t$?

Comment: Welcome. And $0\leq k<1$? you could take a look at:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping

Comment: May be use the factorization
$$f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)(1-[x+y]).$$
Sure looks like the latter factor has absolute value $\le1$.

Comment: Actually, that which you speak of is a strict contraction. I want to show that it is a contraction but not a strict one.

Comment: That curve is a parabola and maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$

Comment: What’s wrong with computing the derivative and showing that it’s $\le 1$ in absolute value?

Answer (score 1):

**I don't think it is!**

To be a contaction we would have $|f(x)-f(0)| \le C|x-0|$ for some contraction constant $C<1$.

This simplifies to $|f(x)| \le C|x|$ or $|f(x)|/|x| \le C$.

To be a contraction the above must hold for all $x$ and some fixed $C$. But the left-hand-side tends to $1$ as $x \to 0$. Hence we have $1- \epsilon < C$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ and so $C \ge 1$ which is a contradiction.

---

**Weak Contraction?**

To prove that $|f(x) -f(y)| < |x-y|$ just use how $$f(y) = f(x) + \int_x^y f'(t)dt$$

and prove all $|f'(t)| < 1$ over $[0,1]$ except at the endpoints. The endpoints do not contribute to the integral.

Comment: Thanks for your time. If I was trying to prove that it is a strict or strong contraction, your definition is correct. However, I am trying to show that it is a contraction and not a strict one.

Comment: $f$ is a (weak) contraction since, as mentioned in a previous remark,   $f(x)-f(y)=(1-(x+y)) (x-y)$ and $-1<1-(x+y)< 1$ for $0\leq x,y\leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I understand your argument. However I cannot quite grasp how to perform the factorization on $|x-y|+|y^2-x^2|$ to get to $1-|x+y|$ and not $1+|x+y|$.

Comment: $x-x^2-(y-y^2)=(x-y)-(x^2-y^2)=(x-y) -\\(x-y)(x+y)=(x-y)(1-(x+y))$.

Comment: @VSeini Contraction means the constant $C$ is strictly less than $1$. Allowing $C=1$ would be called something like a weak contraction, nonexpansive map, or a short map.

Comment: @Daron This is the defintion of a contraction according to Terence Tao: Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $f\colon X \to X$ be a map. We say that $f$ is a contraction if we have$ d(f(x),f(y)) \leq d(x, y) $for all $x, y \in X$.We say that $f$ is a strict contraction if there exists a constant $0 <c< 1$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq cd(x, y)$ for all $x, y \in X$; we call $c$ the contraction constant of $f$.

Comment: What Terence Tau calls a strict contraction is more commonly called a contraction.